# Sum of value based on the key PHP

Tags: php, arrays

We have and array like below in PHP, and want to create a new array in the new array there should be the unique key and the value from the same key should be added.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [58] => 32.00
        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [58] => 34.00
        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [57] => 26.00
        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [57] => 27.00
        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [56] => 16.00
        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [56] => 17.00
        )

)
```

We want to create new array with the help of the above array. 
The value of same key should be added.
The output of new array should be like below.

```
Array
(
    [58] => 66
    [57] => 53
    [56] => 33
)
```

code is below

The output of minmaxarray is

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [min] => 35.00
            [max] => 50.00
            [price] => 26.00
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [min] => 50.00
            [max] => 80.00
            [price] => 29.00
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [min] => 80.00
            [max] => 100.00
            [price] => 32.00
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [min] => 100.00
            [max] => 150.00
            [price] => 34.00
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [min] => 150.00
            [max] => 180.99
            [price] => 36.00
        )

) 

$shippingPrice = array();
            foreach ($minmaxarray as $key => $value) {
                if($price >  $value['min'] && $price <  $value['max'])
                {
                    if($value['price'])
                    {

                    $shippingPrice[][$smethodid] = $value['price'];

                    break;
                    }
                }


            }
            echo '<pre>'; print_r ($shippingPrice);
```

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried to iterate via the foreach loop and make the desired output but not success.

Comment: Your top example looks like print_r's of six separate arrays with one value, rather than one array with six values, so a loop won't work. If you post the code you've tried so far, folks can advise where you've gone wrong!

Comment: show your code please

Comment: Code is $shippingPrice = array();
   foreach ($minmaxarray as $key => $value) {
    if($price >  $value['min'] && $price <  $value['max'])
    {
     if($value['price'])
     {

     $shippingPrice[][$smethodid] = $value['price'];
     
     break;
     }
    }
    
    
   }
   echo '<pre>'; print_r ($shippingPrice);

Comment: @Tushar any update

Answer (score 2):

If your array structure is always the same like you have posted, then this code will work for you:

```
$example_array = array(
  array( '0' => 32.00 ),
  array( '2' => 32.00 ),
  array( '2' => 32.00 )
);

$new_array = array();

// loop through every item in nested foreach
foreach( $example_array as $value ) {
  foreach( $value as $key => $number )  {
    // if the array key not exist, calculate with 0, otherwise calculate with the actual value
    $new_array[$key] = isset($new_array[$key]) ? $new_array[$key] + $number : 0 + $number;
  }
}

print_r( $new_array );
// prints Array ( [0] => 32 [2] => 64 )
```

Code example for your arrays:

```
$shippingPrice = array();

// loop through every item in nested foreach
foreach( $minmaxarray as $value ) {
  foreach( $value as $key => $number )  {
    // if the array key not exist, calculate with 0, otherwise calculate with the actual value
    $shippingPrice[$key] = isset($shippingPrice[$key]) ? $shippingPrice[$key] + $number : 0 + $number;
  }
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r( $shippingPrice );
```

Comment: Can you please my question again I just edited. Thanks

Comment: I dont really understand your update. What is `minmaxarray` for? Please explain a bit  better. If it is your input, what is your expected output?

Comment: minmaxarray  is my input and the output for minmaxarray I pasted above

Comment: If the third code example in your question is your expected output of `minmaxarray` then what is your input array for that? Please make clear what is the content of the actual array and what do you expect what it should be look like.

Comment: I just want to myarray $shippingPrice should look like $example_array which you created  $shippingPrice  array i an created in the above code.

Comment: Please try the `Code example for your arrays` from my answer. I hope this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code

```
function array_flatten($array) { 
    if (!is_array($array)) { 
        return FALSE; 
    } 
    $result = array(); 
    foreach($array as $key=> $value){ 
        if (is_array($value)) { 
           $result = array_merge($result, array_flatten($value)); 
        } 
        else { 
          $result[$key] = $value; 
        } 
   } 
 return $result; 
}
```

You call this function by your array then function will return your expected array.

```
array_flatten($array);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_walk_recursive` instead of 2 `foreach` loop

```
array_walk_recursive($arr, function($v,$k) use (&$r){
  $r[$k] = isset($r[$k]) ? ($r[$k]+$v) : $v;
});
```

Working demo :- https://3v4l.org/MMDEv